# Reference for $|\pi(x) - Li(x)| \ll x^{1/2+\epsilon} \Rightarrow $ RH

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, riemann-hypothesis

It is a well-known result that the Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to the estimate $|\pi(x) - Li(x)| \ll x^{1/2+\epsilon}$. The forward implication was proved by von Koch all the way back in 1901. Is there an accessible reference for the reverse implication?

Comment: A starting point might be https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/the-riemann-hypothesis-in-various-settings/.

Comment: I believe (I am not a professor) that you need the section 5.5 from Edwards, *Riemann's Zeta Function* Dover Publications (2001), especially  the theorem in page 90 . Currently you can read the pages of this section, pages 89-91 from Google Books.

Comment: Thank you @user243301. That is exactly what I was looking for!